# ER_TOO_LONG_KEY in SailsJS 1.0 with sails-mysql

Tags: sails.js

I got this error with sails when I try to `sails lift`:

```
info: ·• Auto-migrating...  (drop)
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error:
error: Error: ER_TOO_LONG_KEY: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I just have one model for now:

```
module.exports = {

    datastore: 'default',
    tableName: 'sci_user',
    attributes: {
        email: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    }
```

It's really simple and I got it from the documentation. I don't understand. It seems it's because of the `unique: true`.

Comment: if you dispose the unique:true line, did it solve the problem?

Comment: yes exactly, that does solve the problem

Comment: There are some workaround that you can try, since the error throws ER_TOO_LONG_KEY.
1. update your mysql
2. switch between utf8/latin base in your mysql `email` column collation type
3. edit the length of the `email` column using mysql console / phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a combination of factors, but the most pertinent one is that `sails-mysql` currently defaults to using the `utf8mb4` character set for string attributes, to allow the use of emojis and other extended characters.  We're working on a patch to make this configurable rather than the default, but in the meantime the quickest workaround is to declare the `columnType` for your attributes directly:

module.exports = {

```
datastore: 'default',
tableName: 'sci_user',
attributes: {
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        columnType: 'varchar'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        columnType: 'varchar'
    }
}
```